# ArrayField returns wrong value

Tags: python, arrays, django, postgresql

I am using PostgreSQL with Django and am trying to use

```
ArrayField(CharField())
```

Neither storing values nor retrieving raises any exceptions, but attepmting to store `["string", "another_string", "string with whitespaces", "str"]` and then retrieve it returns

```
'{string,another_string,"string with whitespaces",str}'
```

This issue does not occur when using `ArrayField(IntegerField())` or `ArrayField(ArrayField(CharField()))`

While I know I could just use JSON or nest the list in another list to get [[strings]] which would be correctly read, I'd like to know why this is happening.

---

EDIT:
As it turns out, using `ArrayField(ArrayField(CharField()))` doesn't work either:

```
Python 3.3.2 (default, Mar 20 2014, 20:25:51) 
[GCC 4.4.6 20120305 (Red Hat 4.4.6-4)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(InteractiveConsole)
>>> from api.models import Game
>>> g = Game.objects.all()[0]
>>> g.p1hand = [["a", "b", "c d"]]
>>> g.p1hand
[['a', 'b', 'c d']]
>>> g.save()
>>> g = Game.objects.all()[0]
>>> g.p1hand
'{{a,b,"c d"}}'
>>>
```

I have no idea why it works in a single instance of `ArrayField(ArrayField(CharField()))`

---

EDIT: With regards to @LongBeard_Boldy, this is what another instance of `ArrayField(ArrayField(CharField()))` returns:

```
>>> g.game_objects
[['Test', '3', '3', '0', 'building', '5', '2', '2', '0'], ....]
```

Comment: I don't see there any issues. this is how PostgreSQL always returns array representation string. if a string type array element contains any white spaces or illegal characters it will always store and show value quoted. if you perform an unnest or select certain array element myarray[1] , value will be returned without quotes

Comment: sorry if am not a django person, shouldt you import postgres contrib? "like from django.contrib.postgres.fields import ArrayField" http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/postgres/fields or http://www.craigkerstiens.com/2012/11/06/django-and-arrays/

Comment: @LongBeard_Boldy I am importing it like that. There is no ArrayField included in django.db.models

Comment: Any updates on this issue? I'm having the same problem ...

Comment: @AndrésMongeMoreno I couldn't figure out this one, so I replaced all my ArrayFields with CharFields and started storing data as JSON dumped strings. If you wish to use this, see json module, specifically dumps and loads functions

Comment: I just did found the error ... It was all about MIGRATING the database XD. As soon as I did migrate the database, everything started working perfectly. Only thing is I'm still trying to find a good widget for it, because the 2 that django provides are aweful: either a simple input and you have to manually introduce the separators or a repetition of the underlaying widget A FIXED NUMBER of times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem and it ended up being a problem with the migrations. I did include the field in the models.py file but I did not migrate, so django was kind of understanding how to process the lists but not how to retrieve them.

As soon as I migrated the database, everything works perfectly.

Comment: I am certain that I did migrate the database, but I cannot try the solution as my problematic code as it was no longer exists. However, if I manage to reproduce the problem in a separate test case I'll flag this as correct answer.